# Finding Affine Transformation between 2 images in Python without specific input points

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, computer-vision, transformation, affinetransform

image 1: [image]

image 2: [image]

By looking at my images, I can not exactly tell if the transformation is only translation, rotation, stretch, shear or little bits of them all.

From what I understand, if I could mark some points between the two images, the getAffineTransformation function in python can get me the transformation matrix.

However, I do not want to mark points (as it is not easy to do so in images like these).

Is there a generic function that could take my two images and give me the transformation matrix?
If not, how do I go about making one?

Comment: I don't think that is possible since there can be more than one transformation matrix, you have to provide some points to determine a specific matrix.

Comment: Thanks for you comment Bruno!
Assuming I have to find the transformation between these two images only: what three points would you reckon?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late but I have been trying to solve the same problem as you and I think I found a solution.

The `findTransformECC` method from the opencv2 library might be what you are looking for. It finds the motion between two images, no need to specify points. It supports different kinds of transformations -- `affine` is one of them. There is a good article about image alignment with examples that use this method: [Image Alignment (ECC) in OpenCV ( C++ / Python )](https://learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/)